# how to create seperate '<p>' tags in the editor after removing empty '<p>' tags in functions.php?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am entering text into a WordPress page and using  to display it. WordPress was outputting empty

tags so I used 'remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');' in functions.php to remove these, This did work but now I can't seperate  'the_content();' into seperate

tags with line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use this function with content p tag: [wpautop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)**

```
<?php echo wpautop(get_the_content()); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this ravi!! but I am still getting 2 empty <p> tags! should I remove 'remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');' from my functions?